# redis-cli command not working as expected on windows machine

Tags: linux, redis, redis-cli, redis-windows

I am using a redis-cli command to bulk insert data and save response to a file using

```
cat file.txt | redis-cli -h 192.168.100.28 --pipe >result.txt
```

on windows

```
type file.txt | redis-cli -h 192.168.100.28 --pipe >result.txt
```

Then on Linux  i can see below response in my result.txt file, but when i run the same command from windows machine the ***result.txt*** file is always empty, Any help ?

**Result.txt on linux machine**

```
All data transferred. Waiting for the last reply...

Last reply received from server.

errors: 0, replies: 9844***
```

**Result.txt on window machine**
nothing always empty although running only `type file.txt | redis-cli -h 192.168.100.28 --pipe`
executes successfully in cmd and i see expected results in console but no data in file.

Comment: are you executing this in the standard cmd.exe shell or a PowerShell console?

Comment: tried on both same result

Comment: Maybe the Windows version writes to `stderr` rather than `stdout`. Try `type ... | redis-cli ... 2> results.txt`.

Comment: maybe you can try Git BASH or something similar on Windows, or maybe setting up a virtual machine with linux or Windows Subsystem for Linux